# How to use external js library functions in Angular 7 project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

We are creating one project in angular 7. We want to use [jquery based library](https://github.com/rvera/image-picker) as image picker.

We have imported the library correctly as 
 import * as 'image-picker' from '..asset/image-picker.min.js'

Also it has been imported as script in index.js with correct path.

Now we are getting stuck about the correct use of this file in Typescript environment. 
For example how to use the below example method of the above library in 
Angular Module in component and templates.

Answer (score 1):

You CANNOT use jquery based libs in Angular context.
It was clearly not a good practice with the old fashionned AngularJS 1.**, now it's not even possible.

EDIT :

According to [this source](https://therichpost.com/add-and-run-jquery-in-angular-7), it's seem's possible.
But for me, it's clearly not a good idea to insist on using Jquery with Angular 7

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion that it is not clearly a good practice but sometimes some clear libraries like image picker comes with a great help and jquery itself seems to be type safe. Yes I understand that we cant assure 100% type safe application when we have any arbitrary js import.

Comment: Your links seem to solved my current problem but we need a good debate on what to do with all good jquery stuff we all, you me and world develop with the new angular context.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this library using jquery so
If you using external library you need to include script of that library in your website using script tag or if you using angular cli you need to edit your angular.json and include that script

then use it in your method

```
$("select").imagepicker()
```

You can go to my blog to read detail how to integrate third party library to angular [here](https://ngohungphuc.wordpress.com/2019/02/07/using-jquery-with-angular/)